# Select a Valid Choice with django model forms

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am getting

```
{"car": ["Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."]}
```

error while trying to assign the foreignkey field options using AJAX.

My code fiels are like this.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class CreatePersonView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonForm

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(CreatePersonView,self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['car'].queryset = Cars.objects.none()

class GetCarsList(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        company = request.GET.get('company',None)
        cars = Car.objects.get(company=company)
        cars_list = []
        for car in cars:
            o = "<option id = '{}'>{}<>".format(car.id, car.name)
            cars_list.append(o)
        return HttpResponse(cars_list)
```

and in my Javascript function what I am doing is

```
function getCars(element){
    company = element.value
    if(company.length != 0 ){
        $.ajax({url:'/get_cars/',
            type:'GET',
            data:{'company':company},
            success: function(response){
                $("#id_cars").html(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function(response){
                $("#id_cars").html(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it is giving me not a valid choice option. Please tell me where I am doing wrong. or what will be the correct way to append the valid choices to the foreign key field.
Help will be appreciated

**EDITS : The problem is the queryset assigned to the field i.e**

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = super(CreatePersonView,self).get_form(form_class)
    **form.fields['car'].queryset = Cars.objects.none()**
```

if I remove this statement it works fine. but i have to show a blank list of choices to the user in starting.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are going to achieve and when you get the validation error. I assume your `get_cars` url calls `GetCarsList`. You use `Cars` model there, but provide the code for `Person` model which you don't use. Are you rendering the form using some template? Are you using Django admin to handle the view? Do you use `PersonForm` and do you call `get_form` at some point? Even though a lot of details are missing, my guess would be that the problem is that you assign `Cars.objects.none()` as queryset and as it is empty, the value is not in it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code but I think the specific issue here is that your HTML markup for each option is incorrect. It should be:

`<option value="{0}">{1}</option>`

However, you'd be better off returning an array of `Car` objects to your JS function and creating the HTML in a JS for loop; sending HTML down the pipe is not very efficient.

This could be a typo, but you refer to `Car` and `Cars` (`Car` is the syntactically correct version).

Also, you've got `Cars.objects.none()` as the form's queryset. You need `Cars.objects.all()`.

Comment: Actually in starting I need a blank choice field and whn someone enters a company name the choice field will be filled up with the name or options of related cars. Thats why I am sending the `Car.objects.none' as the queryset.

Comment: I see. I still think the option's format is your problem though (since when you submit the form, each ``<option>`` has no value, so an empty value is sent with the form.

Comment: No, Format is not any problem, I inspect the elements with firebug and everything is fine there. options have both option texts and value

Comment: values are ids of the objects like 1,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7,